# Timing API requests in ruby?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a simple script that pulls data from an API and stores it in a db table.

What I am wondering is what would be the best way to specify the amount of requests I would like to occur wthin a specified time range (1 min or 2 min)?

All help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up your script as a resque task and use resque-throttler to supply a rate limit on that task. I love resque for performing repetitive background tasks.

relative example from resque-throttler docs:

```
require 'resque'
require 'resque/throttler'

# Rate limit at 10 jobs from `my_queue` per minute
Resque.rate_limit(:my_queue, :at => 10, :per => 60)
```

---

For a simpler approach, you could utilize a library like glutton_ratelimit to help with this task. Relative example from this library's read me:

```
class RateLimitTest
    # The class must be extended to permit limiting.
    extend GluttonRatelimit

    def initialize
       @start = Time.now
    end

    def limit_me
        puts "#{Time.now - @start}"
    end

    # Throttle the limit_me method to five executions every sixty seconds.
    rate_limit :limit_me, 5, 60
end

t = RateLimitTest.new

10.times { t.limit_me }
```

Comment: Thanks Brad...most appreciated!